# event sequence in .net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, events

I am new in windows application development. basically i am web developer. but though i want to understand the sequence of events execution in following scenario:

I have win form. it has a button. i am handling the button click event. when i get run my application  as usually FormLoad event must execute first. but what after i clicks the button ? will form load execute again before button's click event Or form load executes after button click event. Even i can check it my self , but as i tried this i found no sense there as i explained. in fact i wanted to reload my win form on button click with some static parameters (kept in static class). guide me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that happens when you click a button in an application, is the click event is raised, and handled.

Why would a native application re-load the window? Free your mind from this web-type-thinking!

In fact, if you want to re-load the window you should probably have another look at your design, it sounds like it's a bit too web-like. Why are you re-loading the window? If it's just to set some properties, then just set the properties in the click event handler.

Comment: yes, you are right. i must be escape myself from web development scope :) . thanks this is working. fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. First form `load_event` is fired
2. After that `button_click` event will be fired
3. If you click button only `button_click` event fired
4. Whenever you click reload that time `form_load` fired.